# Is there a FreeBSD shell command to compile VB, c# and Pascal programming languages?

Tags: c#, vb.net, pascal, freebsd

I was wondering of there is a command in FreeBSD like "javac" to compile C#, VB and Pascal.

Thanks

Comment: You're looking for Mono.

Comment: No there is no such command. What's more, javac is not a FreeBSD command. It's possible that you might have installed a Java compiler on your FreeBSD system. If you want to use a specific compiler, install it, and the read the instructions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably take a look at the [Mono project](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page), and [specifically Mono:FreeBSD](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono%3aFreeBSD#Using_Mono_on_FreeBSD.)

Installing that should at the very least let you compile and run C# applications.

Answer (score 0):

If you install the "fpc" port, you can use "fpc" to compile pascal.